# Pandas count most frequent elements in nested lists inside gropby and get nlargest

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
                           animals
2016-12-26 11:03:10        [dog]
2016-12-26 11:03:13        [dog, cat]
2016-12-26 12:03:13        [elephant, cat]
2016-12-26 12:03:13        [cow, dog]
2016-12-27 11:03:10        [cow, dog, cat]
2016-12-27 11:03:13        [elephant]
2016-12-27 12:03:13        [elephant]
2016-12-27 12:03:13        [dog, cat]
```

I need get N most common animals and their count by date.
For example (N=2):

```
             animal  size
2016-12-26      dog     3
                cat     2
2016-12-27      cat     2
           elephant     2
```

How can i do that in pandas 0.19.x?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions and add some code showing your current attempt.

Comment: @JGreenwell i'm pretty sure that it can be done in line or two but i'm not pandas expert. I have a solution but it's not a pandas way.

Comment: Please take @JGreenwell's comment seriously. Step zero of asking a question on SO is demonstrating your own efforts. While many people will gladly do your work for you, you should not abuse this as this is unhealthy for the site.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it will be helpful for other users working with pandas, sure. Pandas is well documented but has no snippets collection or cookbook.

Comment: @AlexZaitsev - from the offical documentation: [Pandas Cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html)

Comment: @JGreenwell it's more like examples. Most of them are trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***option 1***

- `apply(pd.Series)` to embed lists as part of dataframe
- `stack` to get into a manageable series
- `reset_index` because there will be an annoying artifact left over from stacking
- `groupby` + `pd.TimeGrouper('D')` + `value_counts` + `head` to get job done

---

```
df.animals.apply(pd.Series).stack() \
    .reset_index(1, drop=True) \
    .groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')) \
    .apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).head(2))
```

***option 2***

- `resample` by `'D'` then `sum` to combine all lists from a single day
- `value_counts`
- `nlargest`

---

```
df.animals.resample('D').sum() \
    .apply(pd.value_counts).stack() \
    .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(2)
```

***option 3***

- `list` comprehension to flatten lists
- `numpy.unique` to get unique values and their counts
- `numpy.argsort` to get 2 largest value counts
- `resample` daily and use `apply`

---

```
def big2(s):
    l = [i for l in s.values.tolist() for i in l]
    u, c = np.unique(l, return_counts=True)
    a = np.argsort(c)[-2:]
    return pd.Series(c[a], u[a])

df.animals.resample('D').apply(big2)
```

---

***yields***

```
2016-12-26  dog         3
            cat         2
2016-12-27  elephant    2
            cat         2
dtype: int64
```

---

***timing***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
df.resample('D').apply(lambda x: pd.concat(x.values).value_counts().iloc [:2])
```

Comment: pandas's resampling method is actually a neat method for frequency conversions - so you might consider adding an explanation of what this code is doing.